# Spike train representation

Tags: plotting, graphics, charts

I have a spike train. The data shows the time at which the neuron fired a spike. I want to plot them like this picture:

[image]

Here is the data for one spike train which corresponds to the one of the neurons in the figure above.

[Download the spike train data](http://www17.zippyshare.com/v/20850918/file.html)

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QquMy.png) can be done really easily. But your data are much larger than those on your plot.

Comment: @Öskå I just put the data as a sample of the spike train in case it is needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example with some random data:

```
SeedRandom@0;
dat = Sort /@ RandomInteger[{200, 700}, {3, 25}];
Graphics[{Hue@.5, Opacity@.7, 
  MapIndexed[Line@Outer[List, #, 40 #2[[1]] + {20, -20}] &, dat]}, 
  Axes -> {True, True}, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Thread@{Range[40, 3*40, 40], Range@3}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With your data, it's a different story and it looks like:

```
data = ToExpression@Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Vj4nQNB5"];
Graphics[Line[{{Log@#, .5}, {Log@#, 1.5}}] & /@ data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You can replace your `Table` expression with: `MapIndexed[Line @ Outer[List, #, 40 #2[[1]] + {20, -20}] &, dat]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks! I knew that there was something but I just considered that `Table` was fast enough for this.. :)

Answer (score 6):

`DistributionChart` with `ChartElementFunction->"LineDensity"`

```
spktrnF[data_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
   Module[{options = {ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[None],
                      ChartElementFunction -> "LineDensity",
                      BarOrigin -> Left, BarSpacing -> 0.1,
                      ChartLabels -> Range[Length@data]}},
          DistributionChart[data, If[opts === {}, options, PrependTo[options, {opts}]]]]


SeedRandom@0;
dat = Sort /@ RandomInteger[{200, 700}, {5, 100}];

spktrnF[dat, ImageSize -> 800, AspectRatio -> 1/3, 
             ChartStyle -> "SolarColors", FrameStyle -> 16, 
             FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Neuron", None, None}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could use `ArrayPlot`.

```
t = Flatten @ Import["f:\\spikes.dat"];
p = ConstantArray[0, Max[t]];
p[[t]] = 1;
ArrayPlot[{p[[1 ;; 1000]], p[[1000 ;; 2000]]},
  AspectRatio -> 1/10,
  FrameTicks -> Automatic,
  FrameLabel -> {"neuron", "time"}]
```

[image]

But this approach is bad for data with more than 1000 time records